# How can I replace UTF chars using Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, replace, utf-8, character-encoding

I'm having a bad time with character encoding. It's kinda to understand why this happens when I open my .txt file:

[image]

**Questions:**

1. What's this type of encoding? Why this happens?
2. How can I rewrite my txt file to use normal accents or even without accents and special chars?
3. Is there any special library to handle this? I could create a huge function that will replace() all these chars, but I don't know when or which chars will appear in my future txts.

**My code:**

```
folder = 'E:\\WinPython\\notebooks\\scripts\\script1\\'
txtFile = folder + 'PROF_SAI_318_210117_310117_orig.txt'

with open(txtFile, 'r') as f:
    with open('PROF_SAI_318_210117_310117_clean.txt', 'w') as g:
        for line in f:
            do_something() # what should I write here to 'clean' my file?
            g.write(line)   

print("Ok!")
```

**Output excerpt:**

```
SPLEONARDO SIM\xc3\x83O ESTARLING
GOFLORESTA S/A A\xc3\x87UCAR E ALCOOL
SPFOCO REPRESENTA\xc3\x87\xc3\x95ES E CONSULTORIA
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are using Notepad++ to display your file.  The encoding displayed looks like `cp1252`:

```
>>> b'COMUNICA\xc7\xc3O M\xc1QUINAS'.decode('cp1252')
'COMUNICAÇÃO MÁQUINAS'
```

In Notepad++, on the menu select `Encoding->Character sets->Western European->Windows-1252` and your file should display correctly.

Here's an example that converts to UTF-8 (your output excerpt):

```
>>> b'SPLEONARDO SIM\xc3O ESTARLING'.decode('cp1252')
'SPLEONARDO SIMÃO ESTARLING'
>>> b'SPLEONARDO SIM\xc3O ESTARLING'.decode('cp1252').encode('utf8')
b'SPLEONARDO SIM\xc3\x83O ESTARLING'
```

For your example code, you can do:

```
with open(txtFile, 'r', encoding='cp1252') as f:
    with open('PROF_SAI_318_210117_310117_clean.txt', 'w', encoding='utf8') as g:
        for line in f:
            g.write(line)
```

If your files aren't too large, you can just do:

```
with open(txtFile, 'r', encoding='cp1252') as f:
    with open('PROF_SAI_318_210117_310117_clean.txt', 'w', encoding='utf8') as g:
        g.write(f.read())
```

Comment: Wow. Many thanks! Do you know if is there any hint or cheatsheet that I can use to understand which type of encoding I'm facing? How did you figured that it was `cp1252`?

Comment: @dot.Py cp1252 is common for US and Western European Windows so it is a good guess.